# Show the empirical covariance matrix is a consistent estimator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-theory, statistics

I am reading [these](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eliewang/ECM.pdf) lecture notes. In the notes, it said: When $p$ is fixed and does not depend on $n$, the empirical covariance matrix is a consistent estimator.

I want a proof to show the above and the rate of convergence. I don't know how to prove. My idea is we can set $\bar{X}=0$ WLGS. Thus, the empirical covariance matrix is $XX^T/n$. I don't know how to do next.

Comment: $X^TX/n\to E xx^T$ almost surely by law of large numbers.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you. How to get the rate of convergence?